# Filesystem monitoring

Tags: filesystems, monitoring, disk-usage

A script where we need to come up with a way for the disk space monitoring to be smarter. On smaller file systems, we still want to alert at 90% full, but on larger file sytems, we should only alert when there is only a few GB free.

Can someone please shed some light on this?

Answer (score 2):

There is multiple options, but you need modify below script as per your requirement.

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f
BEGIN{
ADMIN="root@localhost"
threshold=20
"date" | getline date
"uname -n" | getline hostname

    while("LC_ALL=C df -Ph" | getline){
        used=$5
            if($1 != "Filesystem" && int(used) >= threshold){
            print "Running out of space: "$1,used" used on "hostname" as on: "date
            print "mail -s \"Alert: Almost out of disk space: " $1,used" used\" "ADMIN" >/dev/null" | "sh"
            close("sh");
            }
    }
}
```

You can refer below links
http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/shell-script-to-watch-the-disk-space.html

http://mmonit.com/monit/

http://www.linuxjournal.com/content/tech-tip-send-email-alert-when-your-disk-space-gets-low

Comment: Parsing the lines of `df` will break as soon as the mount reaches a certain amount of characters that `df` will print it on multiple lines.

Comment: @gertvdijk No, it's ok with `df -P`, it's designed to be easily parsable (except when device names can contain whitespace).

Answer (score 2):

You could (ab)use the Nagios plugin `check_disk` for this. The advantage is that this piece of software is lightweight, well-tested and probably available by your package management already (Debian/Ubuntu package `nagios-plugins-basic`). Example usage:

```
check_disk -w 10% -c 3 -u GB -p / -p /mnt
```

In this example, it checks two mointpoints `/` and `/mnt`. If it exits with a exit status of 2, your disk has less than 3GB available, if it exits with status 1, it has less than 10% available and if it exits with a status of 0, then neither of the values is reached. Checking for exit status in Bash is trivial, i.e. `$?`.

Comment: Thanks for your advice.yes we can do it with check_disk nagios plugin. But I would like to write it in shell scripting.